# Delphi Dll form on panel key event

Tags: forms, delphi, dll

i have a DLL and main application .
in the main application i create a form from DLL on panel owned by main application main form , the main form has other components (buttons) .
the problem:
when i press key (enter or tab) in DLL form components (edits) the main application main form takes the key and the button on main form click event executed .

Comment: The close voters don't know Delphi VCL

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two distinct VCL instances in your application. One in the main program, and one in the DLL. That is not supported, and it is expected that much functionality does not work.

For instance, type identity does not behave the way you expect. Each module has its own separate versions of the VCL types. So, the executable's `TPanel` is distinct from the DLL's `TPanel` and so on. You can run into serious problems when you pass objects between executable and DLL because you can call methods from DLL on an object from the executable, and vice versa.

The supported way to do what you need is to use runtime packages instead of DLLs. That results in all modules sharing a single instance of the VCL.

If you don't want to use runtime packages then you should merge the DLL and the executable into a single executable module.

Comment: i changed the application var in the dll with the main application

Comment: You can't do that. You can't hope for success with more than a single instance of the VCL. The only viable solution is to have one instance of the VCL. You might not want to hear the message, but that's how it is.